# How to properly colorize HTML tags in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am looking for a way to colorize the HTML start/end tags in VSCode so it's easier to read.  I installed the [Bracket Pair Colorizer 2 Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CoenraadS.bracket-pair-colorizer-2) and configured my `settings.json` file as follows to support colorized angle brackets:

```
"bracketPairColorizer.consecutivePairColors": [
    "()",
    "[]",
    "{}",
    ["<", "</"],
    ["<", "/>"],
    [
        "Gold",
        "Orchid",
        "LightSkyBlue"
    ],
    "Red"
],
```

This works as long as all of the elements have an end tag. However, if a void element is present, then the colored tags no longer line up correctly as seen below.

[image]

[image]

Are there any workarounds to keep the brackets highlighted with the correct colors regardless of void elements?

Comment: Using `<br />` would not be against style guides. Some guidelines* even prefer them (and it is a **MUST** in XHTML) unless you are thinking about `<br></br>` Except Google. Google says otherwise.

Comment: A closing slash on void tags in HTML has no meaning, does nothing, and is ignored by browsers so putting it there is pointless. That some style guides might require it, as you say, is silly at best.

Comment: The only place I can think enclosing a void element is useful would be XHTML. Like you said, this is pointless. Google's Guidelines even do not recommend closing the void element.

Comment: @Rob I understand. I'm just trying to figure out if there's a way to prevent the void elements from breaking the colorized element pairs, without adding the unnecessary closing slash to each one of them.

Comment: sure that is v2 of the plugin? It seems, `consecutivePairColors` is only for v1 and unknown option in v2. Doesn't work for me.